# Using transient objects to specify ids for saving ManyToOne relations

Tags: spring-data-jpa, many-to-one, transient

I want to save a lot of Spring JPA entities by importing them in batches to the database.
Some entities have ManyToOne relations to other Entities.
As there is a large amount of data, I'd prefer not to keep track of all of the related entities in memory to be set as ManyToOne relations for other entities. I just have the id of the relation, not a persisted entity.

I've encountered the following suggestion a few times as a solution for setting the relation anyway:

```
{
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
private Author author;
...
    public void setAuthorId(Long authorId) {
    Author author = new Author();
    author.setId(authorId);
    this.author = author;
}
```

So using a transient object as a placeholder for relating one entity to another. (assuming the related object gets saved as one of the other objects passed to the saveAll() call)

I see no reference of this approach at all in the official Spring documentation.

Is this considered a supported way to save relations based on just the id or would you say it's just a dirty hack?

Comment: The right approach would be to use getReference: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-manager-get-reference

Comment: We did try the getReference approach, but it led to 'unable to find entity' errors and a lot slower behaviour for saving, as the getReference call was causing commits and SELECTS to be executed when saving (which resulted in merging) the entities if we combined saving the entities and the and the entities referring to them in the same saveAll()

Comment: It's explained in the article, but if you are calling one of the setter/getter on the referenced entity, Hibernate will load it first. If you don't do anything with the referenced entity, it's not going to  run a select.

Comment: There were no setters or getters called on any of the references returned by getReference, but still the merge in the save method would cause issues, which is why we discontinued that attempt.

Answer (score 1):

**Using a transient object as a placeholder**

My team was using such approach in production a lot working with Hibernate (without Spring Data). Didn't have any issues with it.

*Drawbacks*

Spring-data uses `merge()` inside repository `save()` method. Hibernate will generate additional (unnecessary) database `SELECT` query, to update a transient object state.

You can use a custom repository with `persist()/update()` methods to avoid an additional `SELECT` query. Described here:

[The best Spring Data JpaRepository](https://vladmihalcea.com/best-spring-data-jparepository/)

**Using getReferenceById() (since 2.7) / getReference() methods**

We are using this approach a lot. It doesn't cause any additional database queries, if you get a reference and save an entity using the same persistent context (`@Transactional` scope).

*Drawbacks*

We need a repository to use `getReferenceById()` method. For example, you can't use this approach in a transient utility method of entity, like `setAuthorId()`.

**Using stateless session**

[Hibernate’s StatelessSession – What it is and how to use it](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernates-statelesssession/)

**Using a custom repository with JdbcTemplate**

To insert a lot of records better to use low level batch with SQL. We are using this approach a lot in production. Don't forget to add `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to the connection URL, if you use MySQL.

```java
@Repository
class NumbersRepositoryImpl implements NumbersRepositoryCustom {

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private final JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public NumbersRepositoryImpl(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public void batchSave(List<Number> numbers) {
        final String sql = "INSERT INTO NUMBERS " +
                "(number) " +
                "VALUES (?)";

        template.execute(sql, (PreparedStatementCallback<Void>) ps -> {
            int recordsCount = 0;

            for (Number number : numbers) {
                ps.setString(1, number.getValue());
                ps.addBatch();

                recordsCount++;
                if (recordsCount % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                    ps.executeBatch();
                }
            }

            ps.executeBatch();
            return null;
        });
    }

}
```